# jvectormap map and markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

This is my default html file for web app project. I get error:

> JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

I presume that there is a problem with jquery. This is my first time dealing with html and java script, all advice appritiated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jVectorMap demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#world-map-markers').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill',
            scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            hoverColor: false,
            markerStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#F8E23B',
                    stroke: '#383f47'
                }
            },
            backgroundColor: '#383f47',
            markers: [
              { latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City' },
              { latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco' },
              { latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru' }
            ]
        });
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $ is undefined means, that jQuery has not been loaded. Try window.addEventListener('load', function(){ //your code here});

Comment: I tried and still get the same error.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with loading jQuery. Have you checked network traffic if 'http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask' is actually downloaded?